# If I go into battle with a character at Max level does their experience get distributed to the rest of the party?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

If I have 5 people in my party and gain 5000 experience every character gets 1000 experience. If one of those character is max level do the 4 remaining characters get 1250 experience or do they still only get 1000 experience each and I lose out on the 1000 the maxed character would have gotten?

Comment: I'm not sure but I dont think it will distribute the EXP.  This should be pretty simple to test.  Just go into a low level zone with a maxed level and 1 non maxed level and check out how much their exp increases.  You should be able to look a the direct numbers to tell.

Comment: I don't have a maxed out character atm.

Comment: I just finished out my stamina in the middle of a dungeon so I can't check but once you get a character to 50, try testing this before you break their cap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the EXP will not be distributed to the other party members if someone in your party is max level, the EXP is wasted. Effectively, having a maxed out character in your party is the same as finishing a dungeon with a dead character, said character's share of EXP will go to waste.

It should be noted though that if you bring a smaller party into a dungeon, each member will gain more EXP. In your example, leaving your maxed out party member at home and bringing only 4 characters will yield 1250 EXP per characters if the dungeon rewards 5000.

Comment: I just confirmed that a max level character does not have their experience re-distributed.